# Probability of something happening at least n out of m times

Tags: code-golf, math, probability-theory

Write a program or function, that given a success probability *p*, a number *n* and a number of trials *m* returns the chance of **at least** *n* successes out of *m* trials.

Your answer must be precise to at least 5 digits after the decimal.

Test cases:

```
 0.1, 10, 100 -> 0.54871
 0.2, 10, 100 -> 0.99767
 0.5, 13,  20 -> 0.13159
 0.5,  4,   4 -> 0.06250
0.45, 50, 100 -> 0.18273
 0.4, 50, 100 -> 0.02710
   1,  1,   2 -> 1.00000
   1,  2,   1 -> 0.00000
   0,  0,   1 -> 1.00000
   0,  0,   0 -> 1.00000
   0,  1,   1 -> 0.00000
   1,  1,   0 -> 0.00000
```

Comment: Would you care to include a formula to those of us who haven't studied binomial distribution?

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry, that is part of the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2ṗ’S<¥ÐḟCạ⁵P€S
```

Reads **m**, **n** and **p** (in that order) as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MuG5l-KAmVM8wqXDkOG4n0PhuqHigbVQ4oKsUw&input=&args=NA+NA+MC41)

Note that this approach requires **O(2<sup>m</sup>)** time and memory, so it isn't *quite* efficient enough for the test cases where **m = 100**. On my machine, the test case **(m, n, p) = (20, 13, 0.5)** takes roughly 100 seconds. It requires too much memory for the online interpreter.

#### How it works

```
2ṗ              Cartesian product; yield all vectors of {1, 2}^n.
  ’             Decrement, yielding all vectors of {0, 1}^n.
      Ðḟ        Filter; keep elements for which the link to the left yields False.
     ¥          Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain.
   S              Sum, counting the number of ones.
    <             Compare the count with n. 
        C       Complement; map z to 1 - z.
         ạ⁵     Compute the absolute difference with p.
           P€   Compute the product of each list.
             S  Compute the sum of all products.
```

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
BetaRegularized[#3,#,1+#2-#]&
```

Takes input in the order `n,m,p`. Mathematica is so good, it even golfs your code for you:

[image]

`BetaRegularized` is the [regularised incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
function(p,n,m)pbeta(p,m,1+n-m)
```

*edit - 1 byte switching to beta distribution (along the lines of @Sp3000 Mathematica Answer)*

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda p,n,m:m and(1-p)*f(p,n,m-1)+p*f(p,n-1,m-1)or n<1
```

The recursive formula for binomial coefficients, except the base case `m==0` indicates whether the remaining number of required successes `n` is nonnegative, with [`True/False` for `1/0`](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9064/20260). Because of its exponential recursion tree, this stalls on large inputs.

Comment: To test out this answer for large cases, add caching using `from functools import lru_cache; f = lru_cache(None)(f)`.

Comment: @orlp Thanks, I confirmed the large test cases.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 73 bytes

```haskell
g x=product[1..x];f p n m=sum[g m/g k/g(m-k)*p**k*(1-p)**(m-k)|k<-[n..m]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, <s>78</s> 71 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo!

```
@(m,k,p)sum(arrayfun(@(t)prod((1:m)./[1:t 1:m-t])*p^t*(1-p)^(m-t),k:m))

ans(100,10,0.1)
0.5487
```

The arrayfun function is no fun, but I haven't found a way to get rid of it...

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
AQJEsm**.cHd^Jd^-1J-HdrGhH
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQJEsm%2a%2a.cHd%5EJd%5E-1J-HdrGhH&input=10%2C100%0A0.1&debug=0)

Uses standard cumulative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
JEKEcsmgsm<O0QKJCGCG
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JEKEcsmgsm%3CO0QKJ%5ET3%5ET3&input=0.1%0A10%0A100&debug=0)

Note: CG is a very large number which the interpreter cannot handle. Therefore, the number of trials have been lowered to ^T3 which is one thousand. Therefore, the link produces an inaccurate result.

Uses pure probabilistic approach.

Comment: I don't think a probabilistic approach would be valid for this question, but we'd have to ask @orlp

Comment: You need on the order of 1/c^2 trials to get within accuracy c with high probability, so that would be ~10^10 for five decimal places.

Comment: CG is a very large number. In fact, it is the string "abc...z" converted from base-256 to decimal.

Comment: ^TT would be 10^10, and ^T11 would be 10^11.

Comment: @Sp3000 I am not sure if that would ping \@orlp

Comment: @Sp3000 If you can guarantee 5 decimals of precision somehow through probabilistic means, go ahead.

Comment: @KennyLau It didn't, but I'm lurking.

Comment: I can guarantee 5 decimal places.

Comment: If "probabilstic" means random, you can't _guarante_ an accurate value, no matter how many realizations you average. In fact, the result is different every time.

Comment: It is *highly improbable* that it is ***not*** accurate to 5 decimal places.

Comment: There is always a _nonzero_ probability that the result is not accurate to 5 decimal places. Therefore it doesn't fulfill the requirement _Your answer must be precise to at least 5 digits_

Comment: In science, ***highly improbable*** is equivalent to *impossible*.

Comment: But this is not science, this is maths :-)

Comment: Let the poster judge.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES7), 82 bytes

```
(p,n,m)=>[...Array(++m)].reduce((r,_,i)=>r+(b=!i||b*m/i)*p**i*(1-p)**--m*(i>=n),0)
```

Saved 1 byte by using `reduce`! Explanation:

```
(p,n,m)=>               Parameters
 [...Array(++m)].       m+1 terms
  reduce((r,_,i)=>r+    Sum
   (b=!i||b*m/i)*       Binomial coefficient
   p**i*(1-p)**--m*     Probability
   (i>=n),              Ignore first n terms
   0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 23 bytes

```
y2$:Xni5M^1IG-lG7M-^**s
```

Inputs are in the order `m`, `n`, `p`.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eTIkOlhuaTVNXjFJRy1sRzdNLV4qKnM&input=MTAwCjEwCi4xCg)

This does a direct computation summing the terms from `n` to `m` of the [binomial probability (mass) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 26 bytes

```
@(p,n,m)1-binocdf(n-1,m,p)
```

This is an anonymous function. To use it, assign it to a variable.

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/nZ1KST).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁵C*ạ×⁵*¥×c@
R’çSC
```

Reads **n**, **m** and **p** (in that order) as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG1QyrhuqHDl-KBtSrCpcOXY0AKUuKAmcOnU0M&input=&args=MTA+MTAw+MC4x)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

Precise to 10 decimals, could be adjusted anywhere from 0-14 decimals with more code.

```
Prompt P,N,M:1-binomcdf(M,P,N-1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 54 bytes

```haskell
(p%n)m|m<1=sum[1|n<1]|d<-m-1=(1-p)*(p%n)d+p*(p%(n-1))d
```

Defines a function `(%)`. Call it like `(%) 0.4 2 3`.

Comment: n<1 instead of n<=0.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
Sum[s^k(1-s)^(#3-k)#3~Binomial~k,{k,##2}]/.s->#&
```

Uses the binomial distribution probability formula to calculate the chance of *k* successes for *k* from *n* to *m*. Handles the edge cases by using a symbolic sum where *s* is a symbolic variable for the probability that is later replaced with the actual value *p*. (Since *s*<sup>0</sup> = 1 but 0<sup>0</sup> is indeterminate.)

[image: Example]